# How to do an enhanced User Interface with a Notifyer Icon?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, notifications

I'd like to display a hierarchical data in my notifications.

Comment: Welcome.  Your question is perhaps too broad and if so off-topic for SO.  Any code to show?  [mcve].  Good luck

Comment: Why is it broad? I want to make a pop up that looks like the picture. I get my data from TeamCity and filter it because TeamCity's notifyer is not very flexible and can't be used.

Comment: It's too broad because your question is essentially a _set of requirements_ with no code to show.   What have you tried?  Do you have a specific problem? [mcve]. [ask]

Comment: I've tried Baloon Tooltips. I can do Title and text and image. But I can't format text like a list of items or a tree. I've also tried WinForm simulating notification but it behaves different from BallonToolTip in case of two monitors or several notifications at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. I decided to go with [Toast Headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/toast-headers)
It has grouping I needed: [Toast with headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWYEj.png)